# How do i validate a form to show me a thank you page

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

i have a problem to show a thank you page when the form has been filled correctly without errors. I have created a component that I import in my app.vue file. But when I try to call it, it does not work. My code can detect errors with the fetch, and since I don't have a valid URL, it will show a 404 error, and that is correct, but, if the form is filled without error, witch also is validated, it must direct the user to the greetings page when I press the button "send". Can someone help me please?.

```js
< script setup >
  import {
    ref,
    reactive
  } from 'vue';
import Greetings from './components/Greetings.vue'

const formData = reactive({
  name: '',
  phone: '',
  message: '',
  subject: 'general',
})

const subjects = [{
    value: 'general',
    label: 'Personal information'
  },
  {
    value: 'question',
    label: 'Ask your question'
  },
  {
    value: 'support',
    label: 'Support help'
  }
]

const validate = () => {
  errors.value = []
  if (formData.phone == '') {
    errors.value.push({
      message: 'Phone number is missing'
    })
  } else if (!/^\d+$/.test(formData.phone)) {
    errors.value.push({
      message: 'Please enter a valid phone number'
    })
  }

  if (formData.name == '') {
    errors.value.push({
      message: 'Name is missing'
    })
  } else if (formData.name.length < 3) {
    errors.value.push({
      message: 'The name must not be less than three letters'
    })
  }
  return errors.value.length === 0
}

const send = (e) => {
  const isFormValid = validate()
  console.log(isFormValid)

  if (isFormValid) {
    fetch('URL', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => {
        alert('Sorry, something went wrong!', response.status);
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
}
const errors = ref([]) <
  /script>
```

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="send">
    <h1>Information</h1>

    <label for="alternativ">Your choice</label>
    <select id="alternativ" v-model="formData.subject">
      <option v-for="subject in subjects" :value="subject.value">{{ subject.label }}</option>
    </select>

    <div v-if="formData.subject !== 'support'">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" v-model="formData.name">

      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      <input id="phone" v-model="formData.phone" type="tel" maxlength="10">
      <p v-for="error in errors" class="error">{{ error.message }}</p>
      <textarea v-if="formData.subject === 'question'" id="message" v-model="formData.message"
        placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>

    <p v-if="formData.subject === 'support'">Technical support is performed by our expert in the chat.</p>
    <button v-if="formData.subject === 'support'" type="submit">Open support</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: your code shows you not using the `Greetings` component at all besides importing it.  is your question missing code?  Vue Router would make a lot of sense to use, but a simple `v-if` / `v-else` on your form and Greetings component with a submit function that toggles between the two would be simple to do as well.  What have you tried and/or how are you trying to "navigate" to this page or component?

Comment: @yoduh, sorry my misstake. In this task you cannot use router since there is a way to do this without it. I know it would be more easier.. i have try to make a if in the validate funtion and then call it on the Burton with an onclick, but it does not work. But i understand your idea, thank you. I’ll post the code of what i have done later. Thank you.